# Limit Results From Unique Array

Tags: php, arrays, database, string, loops

I have a database select query that returns a comma delimited list of results from a column from multiple rows, and the code filters the duplicated strings which is working very well.

However, I want to **limit the number of strings returned from array_unique** - since I cant use a typical ++counter and break with this filter, I can't figure out how to return only 5 strings for example instead the entire filtered array (which is about 300 unique strings returned).

What I wrote:

```
foreach ($tags as $row) {
   $filter = array_unique($row);
      foreach (explode(',', trim($sep['tags'])) as $tag) {
         printf('<span>%s</span>', strip_tags($tag));
      }
}
```

I tried

```
$filter = array_unique($row);
$sep = array_slice($filter, 0, 5);
foreach (explode(',', trim($sep['tags'])) as $tag)
...
```

Which just returns the 300 rows all over again. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this that way? It's not effective at all... and you want to return only first 5 or random 5 or 5 most common or what? does database contain multiple rows that contain multiple tags delimited by comma or every tag is in different row? if first one, it's not a right way to store tags

Comment: I desire the first 5 rows, allowing the user to click "See More..." which loads more results - ajax. Each database row contains upwards of 2 of the same strings - but each row has about 4 comma separated strings, however the query it is selecting about 2000 rows, producing a filtered 300 results from the query. I know this is not the way, but it is our way until we move these to a table with a relational link between the 2.

Comment: I feel like the root cause of this issue might be a poor database design. It wasn't totally clear but it sounds like maybe you are storing multiple values in the same field? I think it would help us to have some sample data and see your query, so we've got a clearer picture of the overall situation

Answer (score 0):

1. It would have been better if the tags are stored as different rows in your database or json.
2. Working with your data, you can break the line when you've gotten enough count.

```
$tags = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,c,e,x';
foreach (array_unique(explode(',', trim($tags))) as $index => $tag) {
 echo strip_tags($tag);
 if($index+1 == 5){
     break;
 }
}
```